# How can I execute a specific command with the puppet agent from the puppet master when needed?

Tags: puppet

I want to remotely direct the puppet agent to execute a specified command from the puppet master when needed.

I have tried this method, but it did not achieve the expected results. I define a tagged `exec` like this:

```
exec { 'mkdir_test':
  command => '/bin/mkdir -p /123',
  tag     => 'mkdirtest',
}
```

When I execute `puppet kick -t mkdirtest`, the directory located at '/123' will be successfully created. When I execute `puppet kick` or the puppet daemon executes periodically, the tagged `exec` will also be executed, but I want to filter the tagged `exec`. In other words, I don't want the specified command to be executed periodically, just when I need it.

Is there some way to do this with puppet?

Please excuse my poor english.
Thanks.

Comment: You want an orchestration tool, not a configuration management tool. Look into puppet's side product mcollective.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet is a configuration management tool which helps you to build the infrastructure and maintain its state. So if you put an `exec` without conditions, it will execute the command on every run.

You can use `onlyif`, `unless`, `creates` and `refreshonly` to manage the case when you want the command to execute.

As a suggestion:

1. To get better answer, can you elaborate on the conditions when you want the directory to be created.
2. Usage of `exec` is frowned upon. You may want to use `file` resource to create directories. That would give you better control on conditions too.

Comment: Thank you first, Atmesh Mishra.  I have solved this problem with puppet file notify/subscribe.  I create a file, and kick the agent after the file on puppet master has been modified that means I need to do something on demand.